# How to create an array of D3DFORMAT in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++, direct3d, memset

D3DFORMAT *arr = NULL;

This is the reference to the array which is supposed to hold D3DFORMAT typed values. 
How do I allocate the memory for this array whose size is defined by a variable

```
unsigned int arrsize;
```

Should I calculate the size of array in bytes as **= sizeof(D3DFORMAT)*arrsize;**

And than use memset().?

Plz correct me if I am wrong. Or if tere is a cleaner better C++ method to do this. ?

IN advance. Thanks

Comment: is there any reason why you don't want to/can't use a `std::vector` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"cleaner better C++ method" is to use a std::vector

```
unsigned int arrsize = 10;
std::vector <D3DFORMAT> array (arrsize );
```

to cast it to `void*`

```
void* p = (void*)(&array[0]);
```

you will also want to have your values be 0 by default, so just add one more parameter to the constructor

```
unsigned int arrsize = 10;
std::vector <D3DFORMAT> array (arrsize, 0);
```

Comment: Actually after creating the array of D3DFORMAT, (say D3DFORMAT * arr), I need to type cast this to void pointer i.e (void*)&arr & pass to some function which accepts an Void pointer to an array of D3DFORMAT values.  How do I do this if I use vector? Plz show the code snippet to do this. Thank you.

Comment: void* p = (void*)(&array[0]);  Here, are we typecasting only the 1st element of the array (array[0]) , as I need to send the void pointer to the entire array of D3DFORMAT values ?   SO shouldn't it be like this   void* p = (void*)(&array);  ?  Plz correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @codeLover, pointer to the first element is the same as pointer to the array. `(void*)(&array)` will give a pointer to the vector object rather than the array it incapsulates

Comment: Excellent response. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Like this

```
D3DFORMAT* arr = new D3DFORMAT[arrsize];
```

`memset` might work, or it might crash your program. It all depends on how `D3DFORMAT` has been defined. Can you post the definition of `D3DFORMAT`?

Just noticed you asked for a better method. The better method very likely is

```
std::vector<D3DFORMAT> arr(arrsize);
```

but again, it does depend on how `D3DFORMAT` is defined.

Comment: It is a standard Direct3D type, in this case an enum., This presumably means that it is stored as a plain old 32bit integral value.

Comment: OK in that case memset would work, and a vector would work. Do it the easy way, use a vector.